# iOS Sprite Kit SKSpriteNode's setPosition not working

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making an iOS game that uses `SKSpriteNode` to create and control a character as well as enemies.  I have used `[mySprite setPosition:myPosition]` in the past and it worked beautifully.  This does not work at all now.  I have made some pretty big changes in my code, but nothing that should affect this.  It works under one file, but not another that has the same exact code within it.  I am wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that I am using an external display instead of the device's screen.  I use the following code to initialize the `SKView`.

```
//set up the skview
self.skView = self.mirroredScreenView;
self.skView.showsFPS = NO;
self.skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

// Create and configure the scene.
scene = [AirPlayMyScene sceneWithSize:self.mirroredScreenView.frame.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

And within the `SKScene` I use this:

```
//set up player sprite
playerSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Player"];
[playerSprite setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.5)];
[playerSprite setXScale:0.5];
[playerSprite setYScale:0.5];
[playerSprite setPosition:CGPointMake(screenWidth / 2, playerSprite.frame.size.height / 2)];
[self addChild:playerSprite];

//move player sprite
movePoint = CGPointMake(playerSprite.position.x, playerSprite.position.y + playerSprite.frame.size.height);
[playerSprite setPosition:movePoint];
```

This has always moved the player one frame height in the past and in another file, but does absolutely nothing in this circumstance.  I have spent hours on this issue and it is quite irritating.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note that these are all properties, so you can write these more readable as: "playerSprite.xScale = 0.5;" etc if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code

```
//move player sprite
float movePoint = CGPointMake(playerSprite.position.x, playerSprite.position.y +   playerSprite.frame.size.height);
[playerSprite setPosition:movePoint];
```

in the update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime method,
or you can use SKAction method on the node.

```
SKAction moveToY:(CGFloat) duration:(NSTimeInterval)
```

For example, if you want your player to move to the place where you touch, you can do:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(location.x - self.hero.position.x, location.y - self.hero.position.y);
    CGFloat angleRadians = atan2f(diff.y, diff.x);
    [self.hero runAction:
     [SKAction sequence:@[
                          [SKAction rotateToAngle:angleRadians duration:0.2],
                          [SKAction moveByX:diff.x y:diff.y duration:1.0]]]];
}
```

Comment: I have never seen this way of doing this before... could you please give me an example of how it would be done?

Comment: @ConnorWagner if you use the update method, you should calculate the distance between the player position and the destination which is very trouble, so you should use the action, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but the sprite still stays put.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this as well.

To use `scene.frame`, use it in the `-(void) didMoveToView` function.